# Chartjs line graph point hover animation buggy / jumpy

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make a line graph in chart.js that shows the point when you hover over an index. If you move the mouse quickly, it seems the hover animation can bug and plays the animation on points you are clearly not hovering over. You can see what I'm referring to here https://jsfiddle.net/yoh9L1km/3/ as well as https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/linear/step-size.html but it is a bit harder to see on their example since the hover animation is slight.

I have tried changing the mode to x or x-index with no luck. It would be acceptable to me if there was no point hover animation, but when I set the hover animationDuration to 0, the tooltip animation is also instant which I don't want.

it won't let me post without adding some code so

```
hover: {
  mode: 'index',
  intersect: false,
  animationDuration: 0
},
tooltips: {
  mode: 'index',
  intersect: false
}
```

edit: figured this next section out.

Also, unrelated but if anyone has any ideas on how to add a vertical dotted line connecting just the point I am hovering over and the x axis index, I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in the latest version of Chart.js. I've pulled the latest from Github, built it and tested, and the issue you're seeing no longer exists. Fiddle provided at https://jsfiddle.net/8rc6y9zg/.

I think it was [this commit](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/commit/b73b8f98633f399ac804d52bb0c8ed6d2212d3ea) that fixed it (but haven't trawled through the repo checking!).

The latest public release is 2.9.3, you can build and self-host the 3.0 alpha release if you can't wait for the next release.